# Can I maintain session with token based authentication system?

Tags: php, api, session, cakephp, token

I'm developing web services for mobile application in CakePHP (I've already completed web application ). I'm using token base authentication system. In one module session variable ( example 'Selected_Wedding_Id' ) is used. Is that possible to have session variables  with token authentication?